# python subprocess.call can not find dylib in mac

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, intel-mkl

I have a C++ program using Intel-mkl, after compiling the code (assume the executable is `a.out`), I can run it in terminal

```
/Users/hshi/test/a.out
```

which works perfectly fine.

If I use python `subprocess.call` to run `a.out`, the python code looks like

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call( "/Users/hshi/test/a.out", shell=True)
```

Then run the python script, it has an error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/hshi/test/a.out
  Reason: image not found
```

I assume the python script should work the same as if I run `/Users/hshi/test/a.out` in the terminal.

I am using the MacBookPro. I already add Intel-mkl path to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`, using

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Users/hshi/Library/Intel/mkl/lib
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/Users/hshi/Library/Intel/mkl/lib
```

in `~/.profile`.

The `a.out` is compiled by cmake, compiling flags look like

```
/Users/hshi/Library/openmpi-intel/bin/mpicxx  -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG 
 -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/complexDoubleErrorAnalysis.dir/complexDoubleErrorAnalysis.cpp.o  -o a.out 
-Wl,-rpath, /Users/hshi/Library/Intel/mkl/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib 
/Users/hshi/Library/Intel/mkl/lib/libmkl_core.dylib 
/Users/hshi/Library/Intel/mkl/lib/libmkl_sequential.dylib -lm -ldl -lpthread
```

I feel like compiling the code is fine, the problem might be Python does not load my environment path. Thank you for your help.

=========================

The problem can be solved if I create symbolic link to /usr/local/lib.

I also find some interesting information online https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/231

```
In the latest release off OS-X using the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is not 
possible unless System Integrity Protection (SIP) is disabled.

Meaning that setting the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH will have no effects on 
spawned sub shells and therefore using the node client is no longer 
possible unless one turns off (SIP) as explained here."
```

I guess python subprocess.call can not load DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: What does this have to do with the  C++ programming language?  If it does, please provide the source code.  If not, please remove the C++ tag.  It doesn't matter what language a program is written in once it is compiled and linked if you're just trying to run it.

Comment: Thanks, xaxxon. C++ flag removed. Any thoughts about the questions?

Comment: No.  I only found it because it had C++ tag on it -- and knowing C++ didn't allow me to answer any part of it, which is why I made the comment that I did.

Comment: On Mac you would usually add `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `~/.bash_profile`...

Comment: Thanks, I actually add to ~/.bash_profile too, it does not work.

Comment: This question offered me so far the only working solution (creating a symbolic link to /usr/local/lib to make this environment variable work in Python). Thanks!